# Unity constructor injection not resolving repositories as expected

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, repository-pattern, repository

I'm using Unity to resolve [Mike Hadlow's implementation of generic repositories](http://code.google.com/p/sutekishop/) (linq to sql flavor) targeting multiple databases. The container configuration that works:

```
container.RegisterType<IConnectionStringProvider, HistoryConnectionProvider>(new TransientLifetimeManager())
         .RegisterType<IConnectionStringProvider, MetaConnectionProvider>("meta", new TransientLifetimeManager())
         .RegisterType<IDataContextProvider, DataContextProvider>(new TransientLifetimeManager())
         .RegisterType<IDataContextProvider, DataContextProvider>("meta", new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IConnectionStringProvider>("meta")))
         // this registration of Repository<> resolves the history database by default
         .RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>), new TransientLifetimeManager());
         // anything not targeting this database has to be declared
         .RegisterType<IRepository<SpecificType>, Repository<SpecificType>>(new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<DataContextProvider>("meta")));
```

This seems unnecessarily verbose. So I'm currently trying different approaches. Using individual interfaces for each database:

```
IConnectionStringProvider historyConnectionProvider = new ConnectionProvider(connections.HistoryConnectionString);
IConnectionStringProvider metaConnectionProvider = new ConnectionProvider(connections.MetaConnectionString);

container.RegisterType<IDataContextProvider, DataContextProvider>("history", new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(historyConnectionProvider))
         .RegisterType<IDataContextProvider, DataContextProvider>("meta", new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(metaConnectionProvider))
         .RegisterType(typeof(IHistoryRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>), new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDataContextProvider>("history")))
         .RegisterType(typeof(IMetaRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>), new TransientLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IDataContextProvider>("meta")));
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The result is the last type of IDataContextProvider registered getting injected into every type of Repository. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution to the original question**

Unity needed a unique type, as well as interface. I'm still unsure as to why constructor injection didn't handle this. This works:

```
// where IMetaRepository<T> and MetaRepository<T> both are derived place holders
container.RegisterType(typeof(IMetaRepository<>), typeof(MetaRepository<>), new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

Unfortunately, this sets up a situation where consuming classes need knowledge of where their data is coming from, which I wasn't happy with.

**Better Design**

I wanted to leave my dbmls generated (so this ruled out making my models adhere to a certain interface), so I just threw them in different sub folders, causing the designer to generate a different namespace for each database.

Then, in my Repository implementation, I did the following:

```
public Repository(IConnections connections)
{
  T type = new T();
  var ns = type.GetType().Namespace;
  if (ns == "Project.Common.DAL.History")
  {
    _dataContext = new DataContext(connections.HistoryConnectionString);
  }
  else if (ns == "Project.Common.DAL.Transaction")
  {
    _dataContext = new DataContext(connections.TransactionConnectionString);
  }
  else
  {
    _dataContext = new DataContext(connections.MetaConnectionString);
  }
}
```

I think one step past this would be to build a custom type resolver for unity to check the namespace for me and return to injecting the data context (this will be necessary before unit of work can be implemented). I'm not going to mark this as the answer quite yet in case someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, on the second set of code what is the purpose of naming the separate registrations?  You already have decided to have separate interfaces for each database so there doesn't seem to be a need to have a name on it as well.  I could be misunderstanding though.  Moreover, in the second example, if Respository can fulfill the interface for both IMeta and IHistory, then it begs the question what is the difference between the two.

Had i given you example code how to achieve what you want, it would look very similar to the first example you had which in reality isn't all that much more verbose than the latter.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the response. After we get, let's say, 50 repositories that target the meta database, the exceptions to our default behavior in targeting history would be a substantial chunk of code. Being able to declare IHistoryRepository and get a repo targetting that database, rather than making an exception every time, seeemed easier. As far as naming the IDataContextProviders, I wanted these to have their lifetimes handled by the container (eventually per web request) so felt the need to register them. You're right that there is no difference.